# Coda Slider CSS

Tags: jquery, css, slider, coda

I am using Niall Doherty's Coda Slider on my web site but I am having trouble figuring out why some browsers like Firefox Mac/Windows and IE for Windows are rendering the thumbnail images at the bottom of the page in a vertical row instead of in a horizontal row as Safari Mac and Chrome are correctly rendering. I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the CSS but I can't seem to figure it out.

The url with an example is: http://www.lazruda.com/gallery.php?page=3&cat=72157627372114619

Could someone please help? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the display of your `.coda-nav ul li` class to `display:inline-block` in your coda-slider-2.0.css css file, line 48.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Andres. That was the fix I needed.